# Hiding loading overlay after function has completed

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a page which upon click of a button opens a pop up to confirm deletion an element of that page.   Upon hitting on Yes, the method in the controller is triggered and the element is deleted in the database but when the page is loaded again, the grey loading overlay still remains, and the element which was supposed to disappear is still seen.  Below are my codes.

**CSHTML code of link to delete element:**

```
<div style="float: left; width: 40px; height: 10px; "> @Html.ActionLink
("-S", "DeleteSection", "Section", new { id = @Model.Id }, new { 
onclick = "ConfirmDeleteSection();", @class = "editLink", 
style = "width:30px" })</div>
```

**Javascript: ConfirmDeleteSection() function:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmDeleteSection() {
    var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this section?");
    if (x) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
</script>
```

**Controller: SupprimerSection method:**

```
    public ActionResult DeleteSection(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            //get section by id
            var section = _service.GetSection(id);

            DeleteSection(section);

            return RedirectToAction("Pages", "Section");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log e
            return base.Erreur();
        }
    }
```

**Controller: Pages method:**

```
     public ActionResult Pages()
    {
        try
        {
            var liste = _service.GetListeSection();
            return View(liste);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log e
            return base.Erreur();
        }

    }
```

So as you can see, upon clicking on Yes in the pop up, the method DeleteSection is triggered and the Section is deleted in the database.  It then goes to the method Page which fetch all the sections in the database to display them.  However, when the page is loaded, it has that grey loading overlay, which prevents me from clicking on any element in the page and the section which has just been deleted is still seen.  However, when I refresh the page, the deleted element is not seen. Any idea where the error could be?

**UPDATE:**

When the page is loaded again, in the browser's console I have this:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

The whole Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var linkObj;
    $(function () {
        $(".editLink").button();
        var x = "connecter";
        $('#updateDialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Login": function () {
                    $("#update-message").html(''); //make sure there is nothing on the message before we continue                         
                    $("#updateForm").submit();
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        $($("button", $("#updateDialog").parent())[0]).text("Save");
        $($("button", $("#updateDialog").parent())[1]).text("Cancel");

        $(".editLink").click(function (e) {
            //change the title of the dialog
            linkObj = $(this);
            var dialogDiv = $('#updateDialog');
            var viewUrl = linkObj.attr('href');
            $.get(viewUrl, function (data) {
                dialogDiv.html(data);
                //validation
                var $form = $("#updateForm");
                // Unbind existing validation
                $form.unbind();
                $form.data("validator", null);
                //open dialog
                dialogDiv.dialog('open');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
```

**AJAX call**

```
@model Model.Models.CMS.Section

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DeleteSection", "Section", new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
        }, new { @id = "updateForm" }))
    {
    <div id="delete-message" class="error" ></div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Section</legend>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
            <div>
                Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette section?
            </div>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: You haven't shared some parts of the code it seems. At what point do you trigger the overlay?

Comment: In the DeleteSection method, there is a redirection to the method Page of the same controller,  which loads the Page.cshtml with a list of the Sections.  The list loaded does not contain the deleted section.  In the Page method you have a return View(list).  This should load the Page.cshtml again.  I don't understand why I get that grey overlay.  Do you need more information?

Comment: So how do you know if the "delete" operation is successful?

Comment: Because the element is deleted in the database and the new list does not have that element.  I have added some updates in my question.  Can you please have a look at them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your list is in "Pages" view. Which means you are deleting and viewing from the same page.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult DeleteSection(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            //get section by id
            var section = _service.GetSection(id);

            DeleteSection(section);

            return Json("success",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log e
            return Json("failed",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Your view can be like this.

```
 <div style="float: left; width: 40px; height: 10px; ">
<a class="editLink" id="@Model.Id" style="width:30px" onclick="ConfirmDeleteSection('@Model.Id');">Delete Section</a>
```

You can change your javascript like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmDeleteSection(id) {
        var confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this section " +  id +" ?");
        if (confirmation) {
            $('#loading').fadeIn();
            var posting = $.post("/Home/DeleteSection", {id:id}, function () {
            });
            posting.done(function (data) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                if (data != null && data.toString().indexOf('success') > -1) {
                    location.reload();//reload your page. This is not good. Just remove the section using javascript ex: $('#'+id).hide();
                } else {
                    alert("Delete failed"); //you can get server message from json if you want
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, actually in the '@'Html.ActionLink("-S", "DeleteSection", "Section", new { id = '@'Model.Id }, new { onclick = "ConfirmDeleteSection();", '@'class = "editLink", style = "width:30px" })</div>,  does not call the editLink method, which will do the work.  Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: Ok. Now I saw your javascript. I think it's better to get rid of submit and post to your controller inside ConfirmDeleteSection(). Because you are posting from the dialog, it just hangs in there. It's not getting disposed it seems.

Comment: Also try dialog('destroy') I have my doubts on that though.

Comment: I am trying your way.  I have added my Ajax call above.  It calls the function DeleteSection of the controller.  However, I am unable to pass the  model Section to the controller's method from the Ajax.